# How do I use NPS templates with different IP addresses?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, nps

When creating RADIUS client templates in Network Policy Server, the IP Address field is mandatory. So, when RADIUS clients using that template, they all get the same IP address. This seems wrong.

Is there a way to use the template for clients with different IP addresses? If not, what's the point of the templates? I have tried to find documentation for the template function, but that also seems lacking.